# Android Place Autocomplete always timing out

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the new Place Autocomplete feature and PlaceAutocompleteAdapter from this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceComplete/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java

But the result is always timing out with status code 15.

I have tried changing the query many times , but always the call is getting timed out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to missing com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the manifest file.When we have both google maps api and places api, only com.google.android.geo.API_KEY is required. I have raised the bug with google for the same.
[Bug link](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7824)

Answer (score 0):

Verify follows..

- Checkout permissions in Androidmanifest
- Use currect browser key from Google Console

Debug the key is fine or not from ur browser using the url   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=PLACE_NAME&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

This link works for me http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup.. Please check this link.Browser key is no longer needed.We can use the Android key itself